# DE:HR incomplete sidequest in the beginning?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm playing Deux Ex: Human Revolution Director's Cut and I have the email from Athene Margoulis asking me to find the drug thief. I went through an air shaft down stairs from the cafeteria (like maintnance offices section) and I found a big vertical airshaft. Climbing down the stairs I find a datapad with an email which pretty much proves that Brian Tindall is the thief.

The problem is that when I go back to Ms. Margoulis she doesn't respond to it. Is it a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything. After finishing the first main mission (rescuing the hostages in the factory) you will be contacted by Tim Carella who gives you the (side-)quest "[Lesser Evils](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Lesser_Evils)" which proceeds the story about the Neuropozyne theft.

Comment: That's all? So it makes no difference whatsoever if I find it or not? All this time I'm rescuing hostages and everyone knows who the thief and nothing is being done by anyone?

Comment: I asked myself the same question on my last playthrough and to be honest I don't know. I always found the email before playing the main mission, so I always got the "lesser evils" side quest. But my impression of the game is that it is really hard to miss any side quest.